# Access Localstack elasticsearch domain in Sam local lambda

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, aws-sam-cli, localstack

Created an Elasticsearch domain from Localstack and can able to access the endpoint(Postman | Non dockerized application). When I'm calling the same ES URL from the SAM Lambda application using Axios

http://host.docker.internal:4566/es/us-east-1/idx/_all/_search

Returns as

> "code":"ERR_BAD_REQUEST","status":404

But when I checked Localstack health using

http://host.docker.internal:4566/health

Returns AWS running services

Sharing my Docker file for Localstack

```
 version: "3.9"

services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2
    network_mode: bridge
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - ES_CUSTOM_BACKEND=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR- }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR}
      - ES_ENDPOINT_STRATEGY=path
      # - LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME=localstack

    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    links:
      - elasticsearch

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
```

Do i want modify network in docker?

Please help me to resolve this error